# Sass vs Scss - how should I search for SASS?

Tags: sass

I didn't know how to structure my question, so the mods or someone feel free to change the title.

Whenever I'm searching for "Sass " I get flooded with tons of SCSS syntax and examples. I try all kinds of search tricks and I never (or extremely rarely) get an actual SASS results? What should I search for? It's like it doesn't exist.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCSS has been far more popular, I run into the same issue. They're structured in the same way though, so anything you find explained in SCSS should be relatively easy to translate into SASS syntax, and if your text editor supports regex it's easy to strip out all of the extraneous characters using this expression `/\{|\}|;/`

Comment: Ah, good to hear it's not only me! But like - mixins and media queries for example use + sign and = signs and stuff like that. Either I'm dumb or it just comes to trial and error until gotten right.

Comment: If you spend some time here http://sass-lang.com/guide and toggle back and forth between sass and scss, it'll help give you a better understanding of the parallels between the two syntaxes